# SQLAlchemy - entity not marked as expired

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have multi-thread python3 tool to manage other processes.
I use records in database to mark that particular process is busy now.

```
class Process(base):
    id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('NAME', String(128))
    tasks = relationship('ProcessTask', back_populates="process", cascade="all, delete-orphan", passive_deletes=True)
    """ :type: list[ProcessTask] """

class ProcessTask(base):
    id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    process_id = Column('PROCESS_ID', Integer, ForeignKey('PROCESS.ID', ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    status = Column('STATUS', String(128), nullable=False)
    process = relationship(Process, back_populates="tasks")
    """ :type: Process """
```

For example, tasks have only two possible statuses - "running" and "finished"

I faced a problem:

- thread1 creates task for a process
- thread2 checks availability of that process. Process is busy. thread2 sleep until task marked as finished
- thread1 marks task as finished
- thread2 does not "see" changes of the ProcessTask entity and sleeps forever

I tried to mark ProcessTask entity as expired via `session.expire(entity)` in thread2 - does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

---

This is the code which I use to create session factory:

```
connString = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{userName}:{userPass}@{host}:{port}/{dbName}".format(...)
self._db_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connString, pool_size=100, pool_recycle=3600)
self._db_session_factory = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=self.getEngine())
self._db_session = sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session(self._db_session_factory)
```

Each thread creates its own session by `self._db_session()`

Answer (score 1):

Reason of failure was the isolation level of MySQL transactions.

Default isolation level of MySQL transactions is `REPEATABLE READ`. At first read operation inside transaction MySQL creates snapshot of database and during transaction you read from that snapshot. So you can't read changes made by other threads until transaction finished.

To fix this behaviour I had to set isolation level to `READ COMMITTED`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_transaction.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels