# SQLAlchemy, mysql and concurrent sessions

Tags: mysql, multithreading, session, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have multi-thread python3 app. To access database I use SQLAlchemy 1.0.6 (that uses MySQL sessions).

Database has table `WorkerTask` that contain tasks with different statuses.
Threads of my app (workers) execute given tasks and change its status during execution: 'pending', 'running', 'finished'.

Another thread (monitor) checks statuses of the tasks and perform some actions.
At this point I have a bug - monitor request tasks statuses from database, but receives old statuses of tasks. Seems that tasks states do not change since monitor thread launched and its database connection opened.

I checked row response from MySQL - monitor thread receive outdated data.
At the same time using phpmyadmin I see right statuses of tasks.
So my workers threads persist changes into database, but monitor receives outdated data.

I think this is an MySQL trick tied with its sessions.

How to fix it?

---

UPDATE

Reason of failure and how to fix it described here: [SQLAlchemy - entity not marked as expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476371/sqlalchemy-entity-not-marked-as-expired)

Comment: Are you using transactions?

Comment: Yes. SQLAlchemy use transactions and does not work without transactions

Comment: Looks then like 1 thread has not executed a commit so the other thread is reading the uncommitted records.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy - entity not marked as expired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476371/sqlalchemy-entity-not-marked-as-expired)